# I am trying to run a Forward Stepwise Feature Selection in Python using an algorithmic process. I keep getting the same error

Tags: python

Here is my code:

Here is the additional code you requested

```
def next_best(current_var, candidate_var, target, Revised_Basetable):
    best_auc=-1
    best_var=None
    for v in candidate_var:
        auc_v=auc(current_var + [v],target,Revised_Basetable)
        if auc_v>=best_auc:
            best_var=v
            return(next_var)
```

```
number_iterations=26
      for i in range(0,number_iterations):
----> next_var=next_best(current_var,candidate_var,target,Revised_Basetable)
      current_var=current_var + [next_var]
      candidate_var.remove(next_var)


    TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I have double checked my code. I have tried to restart the kernel. Nothing is working and I am confused. Any advice you can give me on this would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what's going on from your code example. Can you create a standalone example exhibiting the problem? it looks like your next_best function is being redefined somewhere.

Comment: Here is the additional code you requested                                                           
#define next_best():
def next_best(current_var, candidate_var, target, Revised_Basetable):
    best_auc=-1
    best_var=None
    for v in candidate_var:
        auc_v=auc(current_var + [v],target,Revised_Basetable)
        if auc_v>=best_auc:
            best_var=v
            return(next_var)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to understand here is what the error message means. The error is occuring on the lines

```
next_var=next_best(current_var,candidate_var,target,Revised_Basetable)
```

and you are getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

The error `object is not callable` indicates that something on at line is being called as a function, but it is not a function, or to be more precise it does not have a `__call__` attribute.

The only object being called in the failing line is `next_best`, therefore it must not be a function, and in fact it must be a `numpy.float64` instance.

In your provided code snippets `next_best` is defined as a function, however, later, somewhere in code you have not provided, it must be redefined as a `numpy.float64`. Essentially what is likely to be happening is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def next_best(msg):
    print(msg)

next_best = np.float64(12.0)

next_best('do something')
```

Running this will give the same error you are seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "callable.py", line 8, in <module>
    next_best('do something')
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

In your case, the most likely thing is your have redefined the variable somewhere in your current procedure. However it may be obfuscated in a range of different ways, for example an import. The following code will produce the same error:

```
# a.py
def next_best(msg):
    print(msg)
```

```
# b.py
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    next_best = np.float64(i / 2)
```

```
from a import next_best
from b import *

next_best('do something else')
```

The bottom line is you need to scan your code and find where you redefine `next_best`.